# how to store millions of data coming from justdial scraper engine into mongodb manually in an effective way?

Tags: mongodb, database

How to store millions of data coming from justdial scraper engine into mongodb manually in an effective way?

We actually manually running the script to put the .json data into mongodb. It took 8:30 hours to just to insert the data into database and our database is growing like anything (we get duplicate data which we handle after inserting all the records) and it is also consuming lot of RAM. Is there any better way we can do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is a need for sharding your load between many servers - thats most efficient scenario - [see here for more info](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/)

As there is  a huge chunk of data to digest - to run this on same server, please consider :

1. use dedicated SDD drive for mongo data directory (and for indexes as well)
2. use WiredTiger as storage engine (which is default from 3.2)
3. divide input file, as this will reduce swapping (as Japanese says: you can eat an elephant, but don't do it on one dinner :-) )
4. try to build array of some number of documents (let's say 1000)
   instead of processing OneByOne - or AllAtOnce